# Excel import, separando linha em 2 tabelas. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, phpexcel

Estou importando um arquivo xlsx, contendo x colunas, que estao sendo armazenadas em 2 tabelas diferentes. "Editais" e "ItensEditais".
Os registros até a coluna x sao armazenados na tabela Edital, e os registros a partir dessa coluna são armazenadas em outra. Só que cada linha desse arquivo contém o mesmo Edital, e Varios itens para cada edital. Então as colunas que contém informações do Edital, se repetem em varias linhas, o que difere são as colunas relacionadas à Itens de cada Edital.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso adicionar uma ForeignId "id_Edital" relacionada ao "id" do edital.

"EditalImport" está assim

```
class EditalImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        if(Edital::where('id_licitasys', $row['idLicitasys'])->first()){
            return null;
        }
        return new Edital([
            'id_licita'                 => $row['idLicita'],
            'cnpj'                      => $row['cnpj'],
            'licitador'                 => $row['licitador'],
            'uf'                        => $row['uf'],
            'municipio'                 => $row['municipio'],
            'populacao_municipio'       => $row['populacaoMunicipal'],
            'prazo_edital'              => $this->convertDateTime($row['prazoDoEdital']),
            'data_certame'              => $this->convertDateTime($row['data/horaCertame']),
            'prazo_validade_contrato'   => $row['prazoDeValidadeDoContrato'],
            'objeto'                    => $row['objeto'],
            'obs_edital'                => $row['observacaoNoEdital'],
            'obs_licitacao'             => $row['observacaoLicitacao'],
            'url_edital'                => $row['linkEdital'],
            'id_owner'                  => auth()->user()->id
        ]);
        
    }

    private function convertDateTime($value) {
        return date_format(DateExcel::excelToDateTimeObject($value), 'Y-m-d H:i');
    }
}
```

E o meu "ItemEditalImport" está assim:

```
class ItemEditalImport implements ToModel, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row){
          
            return new ItemEdital([
            'lote'                  => $row['lote'],
            'item'                  => $row['item'],
            'prod_licitado'         => $row['produtoLicitado'],
            'complemento'           => $row['complemento'],
            'quantidade'            => $row['quantidade'],
            'preco_ref_unitario'    => $row['precoReferenciaUnitario'],
            'preco_ref_total'       => $row['precoReferenciaTotal'],
            'mandado_judicial'      => strtoupper($row['mandadoJudicial']) == "SIM" ? true : false,
            'exclusivo_epp'         => strtoupper($row['exclusivoEpp']) == "SIM" ? true : false,
            'prod_candidato'        => $row['produtoCandidato'],
            'descricao'             => $row['descricao'],
            'situacao_edital'       => $row['situacaoEdital'],
            'data_situacao'         => $this->convertDateTime($row['dataHoraSituacao']),
            'data_publicacao'       => $this->convertDateTime($row['dataHoraPublicacao']),
            'obs_item'              => $row['observacaoNoItem'],
            'id_edital'             => $this->verificarIdEditais($row)//função para verificar idLicitasys e adicionar o mesmo id do edital.
        ]);
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public function chunkSize(): int{
        return 1;
    }
    private function convertDateTime($value) {
        return date_format(DateExcel::excelToDateTimeObject($value), 'Y-m-d H:i');
    }
   private function verificarIdEditais($value){
    ItemEdital::upsert([
        ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
        ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
    ], ['departure', 'destination'], ['price']);
   }
```

Coloquei uma função (verificarIdEditais) que eu estava lendo na documentação do Laravel, achei que ia funcionar, mas eu nao soube aplicar ela.
Alguém pode me dar uma luz?
Preciso que cada vez que for adicionar um item no "ItemEdital", adiciona o ID do edital relacionado ao Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver criando uma função que identifica à qual Edital o Item pertence, e coloca o ID dele no ForeignID do id_edital.

```
private function verificarIdEditais($value)
{

    if ($edital = Edital::where('id_licitasys', $value)->first()) {
        return $edital->id;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Entao coloquei no item do import para passar por essa função:

```
public function model(array $row){
      
        return new ItemEdital([
        'id_edital'             => $this->verificarIdEditais($row)//função para verificar idLicitasys e adicionar o mesmo id do edital.
    ]);
}
```